# Could not read csv file in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am new to pyspark and I did some initial tutorials. When I am trying to load a CSV file on my local host in the Spark framework using Jupyter Notebook, the below mentioned error pops. My java version is 8.0

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName('sql based spark data analysis') \
    .config('spark.some.config.option', 'some-value') \
    .getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv('C:/Users/sitaram/Downloads/creditcardfraud/creditcard.csv')
```

My error is as follows:

```py
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o55.csv.
      : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while running command to get file 
      permissions : java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null ls -F C:\tmp\hive
      at 

  org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:770)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execCommand(FileUtil.java:1097)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:65
   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error 
   while running command to get file permissions : java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null ls -F C:\tmp\hive
```

Comment: Looks like your program is executing a command that has null instead of some value: null ls -F C:\tmp\hive

Comment: Did you set `HADOOP_HOME` without bin folder? Are you  using `winutils.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try `C://Users//sitaram//Downloads//creditcardfraud//creditcard.csv`